# Surgery replace class file in .ear

Tags: class, jar, ear

I have an .ear file, which contains several jars, and for each jar we have several .class files.

I would like to replace/override single class in that .ear file, without open the .ear then the specific jar, and fold all back.

Any option ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Beyond Compare, is he winner tool for this issue.

This allow compare two folders into jar.

[image: directory diff]